# WFFM radio list field doesn't fire validation when no radio button value has been selected

Tags: wffm

If I set a radio list field as `mandatory`, upon submit it does not display any error message if none of the radio options are selected.

The same happens for checkbox list. Works fine (showing required field validation message) for other field types.

Sitecore 7.2 + Web Forms for Marketers 2.4

> Sitecore support has confirmed that the missing validation on
>   checkbox/radio lists is a bug. no fix yet though

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I had the same issue on a Sitecore8, so not sure if it is related but in our case it was a bug. Two possible workaround were: using a success message instead of success page or uncheck the "ajax mvc form" checkbox.  (put this as comment as I'm not sure it will relate to your situation as well)

Comment: I would create a Sitecore Support ticket.

Comment: This is a known bug, raise a ticket with Sitecore Support and they will provide a fix for your specific version. It's working OOTB on SC 8.1.3.

Comment: @jammykam yes, the ticket is raised. just not sure if i should close the question on stackexchange

Comment: Maybe after you got the answer you can just write an answer here with the reference number for this bug. Then others can use this when they create the Sitecore Support ticket.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bug in the core product which requires a fix from product support.